# How to make touch go through empty layout-area in overlay?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, overlay, android-windowmanager

I'm making sort of a side panel on Android that can be pulled out with a handle. My problem is that the area on the top and bottom of the handle (see area marked in picture) is blocked from touch, because the Layout that surrounds the panel and handle obviously extends there. What can I do about this?

The Panel:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, I understand that you have put both the handle and the side panel in the same parent layout. I suggest to put the handle outside of the side panel parent layout and set it's height and width to wrap_content. By doing this, the layout surrounding the side panel will not extend above and below the handle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I've already thought of that too, but was hoping there was an easier solutions...